# Error when converting mm/dd/yyyy string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a table and I am only given a varchar value:

```
UPDATE table
SET Deadline = CONVERT(DATETIME, '06/18/2012 12:00 AM')
FROM table
WHERE nominal_id = 2650
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 
> Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

But when I do a simple `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '12:00 PM')`, it returns the proper value. What do I seem to be missing here? Should I be CASTing the varchar?

Comment: I'll bet it works if you use `'18/06/2012'` instead of `'06/18/2012'` - in which case it is because you're accepting dates in `m/d/yyyy` format even though your server is set to British or similar regional settings, or your session has set dateformat to `dmy`, or language to British or similar, or both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use unambiguous, region-agnostic strings for date/time literals. In your case this should work better (and you won't need an explicit convert to datetime):

```
'20120618 12:00 AM'
```

I highly recommend you change the input format. If you can't change the input format, then perhaps:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), '06/18/2012 12:00 AM', 101))
```

Comment: I'm old... I've also written about the topic of date queries pretty extensively, e.g. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: I tried this and still got the same error message:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Okay, so what is the data type of Deadline? What is the collation of the database, the regional settings for the server, and the settings for the session that is executing the code and getting the error (`SELECT language, date_format FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID;`)?